# WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/replicated-cache=sso' are not available

Tags: java, caching, wildfly, infinispan

I am using wildFly22 with Java11 and am trying to configure Infinispan cache.

**distributable-web.xml**

```
<distributable-web xmlns="urn:jboss:distributable-web:2.0">
    <infinispan-session-management cache-container="web" cache="corpapp-session-cache-web" granularity="SESSION">
        <primary-owner-affinity/>
    </infinispan-session-management>
</distributable-web>
```

**standalone-ha.xml**

```
  <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
    <!--<transport lock-timeout="60000"/> -->
    <replicated-cache name="sso">
      <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
      <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
      <expiration interval="0"/>
    </replicated-cache>
    <replicated-cache name="routing">
      <expiration interval="0"/>
    </replicated-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="dist">
      <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
      <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
      <expiration interval="0"/>
      <file-store/>
    </distributed-cache>
    <distributed-cache name="corpapp-session-cache-web">
      <file-store path="corpapp-cache" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="false"/>
    </distributed-cache>
  </cache-container>
```

**Error**

```
13:32:45,362 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/replicated-cache=sso' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.transport.channel.web; Possible registration points for this capability: 
                /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/transport=jgroups
13:32:45,366 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/replicated-cache=routing' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.transport.channel.web; Possible registration points for this capability: 
                /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/transport=jgroups
13:32:45,368 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/distributed-cache=dist' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.transport.channel.web; Possible registration points for this capability: 
                /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/transport=jgroups
13:32:45,370 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/distributed-cache=corpapp-session-cache-web' are not available:
    org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.transport.channel.web; Possible registration points for this capability: 
                /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/transport=jgroups
13:32:45,378 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```